# Maximum height of a Binary tree vs height of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Are height and maximum height different metrics for binary trees?

[image]

For the tree above, is the height 2 and maximum height 2+1 = 3?

Comment: What is the context? In which text have you encountered "maximum height"?

Answer (score 1):

Height of a binary tree is the longest path from root to any leaf nodes.
So, height and maximum height has no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The height (or maximal depth) of your tree is, as you say, *2* because that is the largest depth of any node.

The maximum height is a less well-defined term, so unless you specify how you choose to define it, I will interpret literally, meaning the maximum height that a binary tree of this size can have. Since a binary tree requires that a node have **at most** two children, we find that we can just assign each node one single child and connect them all under each other in a long chain. This is essentially a one-dimensional linked list. Since your tree has *5* nodes, the height of such a tree would be *5-1* (because we don't count the root node in the definition you are using). So the maximum height, if interpreted this way, would be *4*. But if you are using a different definition for maximum height, you will have to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition,  height of a binary tree is Maximum of height of left sub-tree of the root node and height of right sub-tree of root node +1.
`MAX(left sub-tree of root height, right sub-tree of root height) + 1`.
And this is also the maximum height of the binary tree.
Now, what you are confused about is the **Diameter** of binary tree.
Diameter is the length of the longest path between any two nodes of the tree. In your example, *height of binary tree* is 2 whereas *diameter of binary tree is 3*.